# How to incorporate different compilers into an android app

Tags: android

My team is designing an Android app and we want to have the user enter code (in languages such as c++, java, python, etc.) and the app will compile the code and execute it. How can I do this? Is there a way to have the mingw c++ compiler or the java compiler loaded into the project, so the code the user types will be compiled by one of the compilers mentioned above?

Comment: Are you asking about JNI libraries for the NDK?  https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: As for other languages -  you'll need some other stuff. https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure. Is that for compiling C/C++ code to make an android app? Or is that about compiling user input within an app?

Comment: Both? *Your Java code can then call functions in your native library through the Java Native Interface (JNI).*